# Append tuples to a tuples

Tags: python, append, tuples

I can do append value to a tuples

```
>>> x = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> x += (8,9)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9)
```

But how can i append a tuples to a tuples

```
>>> x = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
>>> x
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
>>> x += (8,9)
>>> x
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), 8, 9)
>>> x += ((0,0))
>>> x
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), 8, 9, 0, 0)
```

How can i make it

> ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9), (0, 0))

Comment: Just note that in this case technically you are not appending - tuples are immutable, you're creating a new tuple there.

Comment: If you need to be able to extend a tuple, are you sure it should be a tuple rather than a list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
x + ((0,0),)
```

should give you

```
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9), (0, 0))
```

Python has a wonky syntax for one-element tuples: `(x,)` It obviously can't use just `(x)`, since that's just `x` in parentheses, thus the weird syntax. Using `((0, 0),)`, I concatenate your 4-tuple of pairs with a 1-tuple of pairs, rather than a 2-tuple of integers that you have in `(0, 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Add an extra parentheses:

```
>>> x = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6)) + ((8,9),)
>>> x
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9))
```

Notice the trailing comma. This will make you add a new-pair tuple to it.

Also, just a note: This is *not* appending, since tuples are immutable. You're creating a completely whole new tuple.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

[PLEASE SEE NOTE BELOW]

Also this should work:

```
x += (0,0),
```

## NOTE:

*this is unsafe!!* Thanks to Amadan and aIKid for the great discussion.

As Amadan pointed out, this specific case will work only because the assignment operator `+=` has lower priority than `,`, so by the time the two tuples are joined, `(0,0),` has already become `((0,0),)`.

But if you try:

```
((1, 2), (3, 4)) + (5, 6),
```

the result will be a messy

```
(((1, 2), (3, 4), 5, 6),)
```

because `+` has higher priority than `,`, so the numbers 5 and 6 are joined to the tuple separately!
There intermediary stage is then `((1, 2), (3, 4), 5, 6),` and finally this tuple with a final `,` is "corrected" to give `(((1, 2), (3, 4), 5, 6),)`.

Take-home message: using the notation `(5, 6),` is not safe because it being "corrected" to `((5, 6),)` might have lower priority than other operators.

Comment: Python 7.4?! Me wants!! :)

Comment: I'm too new to post a solution without having tried it beforehand, lol

Comment: But seriously, you did try it on your system and it didn't work?

Comment: Are you sure? Here's what i get:

Comment: `>>> ((1,2)) + (1, 3),`
Result:
`((1, 2, 1, 3),)` - Python 2.7.5

Comment: Interesting, looks like this behavior is introduced in Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Oh, weird. `x+(0,0),` does not evaluate the same as `x+=(0,0),`.

Comment: @Roberto I do know that.

Comment: @Amadan Holy cow, this is getting more interesting.

Comment: yup it takes x+(0,0)as first tuple and null as second like (1+2 ,)

Comment: Oh this is weird, I confirm that it doesn't work right at the prompt

Comment: How about we move to chat? The Python chatroom?

Answer (score 1):

in python both `((0,0))` and `(0,0)` are equal:

```
>>> x=((0,0))
>>> y=(0,0)
>>> x==y
True
```

so to get `((0,0))` you need to type `((0,0),)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

>>> x += ((8,9),)

>>> x

((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9))

>>> x += ((10,11),(12,13))

>>> x

((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9), (10, 11), (12, 13))
```

To represent a tuple with a single element, you have to use a trailing comma. And unlike list, tuple is immutable

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> x = *x, (8, 9); x
((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 9))
```

This way you could avoid using the `+` operator, the `+=` operator, and that weird `((8, 9),)` syntax. Using the deconstruct operator `*` is a bit more elegant and slightly more obvious what you want to have happen: deconstruct previous tuple, appending new element onto new tuple, x.